# How to print contents of the array with spaces using the c# ForEach method and store it in a string variable?

Tags: c#

This is what I have done so far:

var words = new[] { "hello", "world!"};

Array.ForEach(words, Console.Write);

My output: "helloworld!" Output wanted: "hello world!".

How do store the output in a variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use string.Join:

```
var joinedWords = string.Join(" ", words);
```

Comment: What is your issue with var?

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct so that this question is "closed".

Comment: @zmbq:  var is devoid of semantic meaning, as is x.  (In my humble opinion).

Comment: I tried Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arr.Reverse())); and it worked, Thanks.